# Docker --network=host in Xenial disables IPv6 on system

Tags: 16.04, docker, ipv6

I chased this for hours before finally finding it was docker doing it. Starting a docker container which is using host networking (--network=host) with a system with IPv6 address configured, and dockerd running with --ipv6, disables ALL IPv6 on the system. It set the disable_ipv6 flag to 1 on all interfaces under /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf. No idea why it's doing this. I guess it's a bug.

Running Ubuntu 16.04

docker-engine=17.04.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial

Answer (score 0):

Just to share more details, I ran into the same problem even without `--network=host`, I'm using netns ifaces between containers. "Fixed it" by starting the containers with `--sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0`

Comment: Tried this - Didn't work in my case. Normal (not --network=host) doesn't disable IPv6. Launch a container with --network=host even with that sysctl, all IPv6 gets disabled :(

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently caused by https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32433 Should be fixed in 17.05.0-ce due for release in May 2017.